# Manga with two girls who are roommates who are isekaied into a place with doors to various places

Tags: story-identification, manga

Two roommates, one a fat girl and one a slim girl, are both isekaied or stucked in a backroom sort of world, or a room with doors that connected all. There's a room filled with water and a room with voice recorder.  At one moment they ran to the forest when they got chased by an entity, and then they found a portal. That's where the part one of the manga ended.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Was it in colour or black-and-white?  Was there anything distinctive about appearance of either character?  Do you remember the names of any characters or places?

Comment: That definitely rings a bell; girls exploring a giant building with higgledy-piggledy interconnected rooms... Can't remember much helpful, though.

Comment: Urasekai Picnic has two female leads, but they're not roommates. Wouldn't call either "fat", but afaik there are other women involved as well. I don't know if any of the other details match, as I haven't read it yet.

Comment: Wakusei Closet is another slim possibility, with two girls in other worlds. I don't think either is a very good match, but could you explicitly rule them out?

Comment: I've read something similar a few years ago. The backroom-type space has strange rules and the one girl experiments to figure them out; there's a plot point with duplicating tables recursively...